# plotting polygons inside loop in R, why this ambiguous behavior?

Tags: r, loops, polygon

So, I want to plot multiple polygons over one polygon using a loop in r. I have read that you need to use print in order to succesively display the polygons over the original polygon. However, that is not what R seems to do. Besides, in a hardly reproducible example, what i find is that either using print or not, the polygons will not plot within the loop. I am using a mac with OS monterrey, btw.

Here is a reproducible example, using print gives a bunch of NULL messages, but does print, not using print still plots. Yet a more complicated example will never plot from within the loop despite plotting everything when i request line by line from within the loop.

```
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

plot(wrld_simpl)
for (i in 1:12){
region=wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME==wrld_simpl$NAME[i],]
 print(plot(region,border="red",add=T))
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what your problem seems to be. It seems like dropping the `print` statement does what you'd like to do - adds multiple polygons over the existing plot.

Comment: My doubt is about the ambiguous behavior of plotting in loops. During a loop, I think It should only plot to the console when using print. However, the example plots either when using print or plot. in contrast my larger loop at home plotted with none of them. However, i discovered where the problem was, there was a line, down the line of plotting, which rendered an error but without stopping the loop. Erasing that line allowed me to plot again to the console, using either print or plot...geez..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confusing print and plot? The plot function creates (or adds elements to) a plot. Whereas print function prints its arguments to the console. Since plot doesn't return a value, print has nothing to print and hence prints NULL.

Btw. you don't even need a loop. Since the loaded data wrld_simpl is of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, the object is subsettable like a dataframe you can just plot the needed indices:

```
plot(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl[1:12,], border="red", add=T)
```

If you need help on a more complicated example, I suggest you share it?